# How to re-use DataTrigger in XAML/WPF ListView to translate boolean to Yes/No using DataTemplate and Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a XAML/WPF user control where I have XAML code that translate two boolean properties (`BoolProperty1` and `BoolProperty2`) to text saying Yes or No. This works fine, but I want to re-use this code so I don't have to add a `DataTemplate` for each boolean property. I assume it can be done with `Resources`, but I haven't been able to find an example where the property (name) is injected into the resource (so there's only one resource definition for all my boolean properties). *edit* Also note that I would like to do this without any C# code like changes to the data model or adding a converter.

Here's the GIST of the XAML (and the code is below): https://gist.github.com/HakanL/c845a3d8921c76f884c8703a97c385ee

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApplication.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Rec. No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RecordNo}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value, StringFormat=\{0:N0\} dB}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="BoolTest1">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolProperty1}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="BoolTest2">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolProperty2}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Instead of TextBlock Styles with different DataTriggers you may use a Binding Converter like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding BoolPropertyX, Converter={StaticResource BoolToYesNoConverter}}"/>`.

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to keep all presentation in XAML, not have to add C# code for a converter since the text strings with Yes/No could potentially be unique to this user control.

Comment: The converter could have properties for those strings, or you pass them via the ConverterParameter property of the Binding.

Comment: It could, but that would sprinkle that code in multiple places in the solution, I don't want that, I want all presentation to be in the XAML. Your suggestion is not wrong, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: That's a misconception. The converter would be generic. You would set its true and false string properties when you declare it in XAML. Good luck however with finding an alternative.

Comment: What I mean for this particular control that the true and false string representations aren't generic, they should be able to say things like "Automatic" or "Manual", which only makes sense in this control, so I don't want a converter for each type of boolean. I understand that I could pass in the string values for true/false, but I'm really trying to find a solution without a converter, even if a converter would solve the problem.

Comment: "*I'm really trying to find a solution without a converter, even if a converter would solve the problem.*" - you know how that sounds, right? Maybe you still haven't understood that you could declare an instance of the converter in the Resources section of the control and set the true/false string properties there once. The converter would be used via StaticResource throughout the control's XAML. It couldn't be more elegant.

Comment: I don't know how that sounds, I'm looking for a solution that is contained in the XAML file, because it would be the most elegant solution for the problem I'm having. I know I could instantiate the converter in the Resources section, but I'm trying to avoid using a converter since it would be a separate dependency that I don't want to have.
It's not always about solving the problem with any possible solution, I'm trying to figure out how to solve it using the constraints I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244487/discussion-between-haukman-and-clemens).